# Getting additional bytes in JSON while sending it via socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, encryption, rsa

So Basically what i am doing is sending an encrypted JSON file from client to server the original file is as follows:

'{ "emp1": { "name": "Lisa", "designation": "programmer", "age": "34", "salary": "54000"}}'

But at the server side I am receiving:-
b'\x9e\xf4\xc7\xc1\x8b\x81\xa1\xb7:\xa0\xc6L\x9e\xef,\nme": "Lisa", "designation": "programmer", "age": "34", "salary": "54000"}}''

Below is My Code for server and client.

Server Code -

```
import socket
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad
import json
import rsa

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 9988

public_key, private_key = rsa.newkeys(1024)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen(4)

client, addr = server.accept()

symmetric_key = os.urandom(16)
encrypted_symmetric_key = rsa.encrypt(symmetric_key, public_key)

client.send(private_key.save_pkcs1("PEM"))
client.sendall(encrypted_symmetric_key)
json_data = client.recv(1024 * 1024)

# Decrypt the JSON file with the symmetric key
cipher = AES.new(symmetric_key, AES.MODE_CBC)
decrypted_data = cipher.decrypt(json_data)
unpadded_data = unpad(decrypted_data, AES.block_size)

# x = unpadded_data.decode("latin-1")

# json_object = json.dumps(x)

with open("file.json", "wb") as f:
    f.write(unpadded_data)



client.close()
server.close()
```

Client Side Code

```
import socket
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import rsa
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad


# Create a TCP socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to the server
client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9988))


server_public_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(client.recv(1024))
encrypted_symmetric_key = client.recv(1024)
symmetric_key = rsa.decrypt(encrypted_symmetric_key, server_public_key)

json_data = open('data.json', 'rb').read()

padded_data = pad(json_data, AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(symmetric_key, AES.MODE_CBC)
encrypted_data = cipher.encrypt(padded_data)

client.sendall(encrypted_data)


client.close()
```

Comment: If I'm reading this right the server sends it's *private* key to the client. Don't do that. You should send the public key. Note that this is still a completely broken key exchange. A MITM can trivially replace the keys. If you want to do something like this you have to have one side send their public key and the *other* side generate and wrap the symmetric key. Have you considered using TLS?

Comment: CBC mode requires an IV, and the IV that was used on the encryption side must also be used on the decryption side. That's not happening here. Other problems here include the private/public key confusion noted in the previous comment an confusion about how TCP sockets work.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I will look into it